# How to make sure my COM server is running correctly

Tags: com

I'm following [this very old tutorial](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/tutorials/article.php/c5567/Step-by-Step-COM-Tutorial.htm) (published on 2001-3-6). It suggests .idl file should be inserted into the project work space. I don't know what this "project work space" means. My best guess is that it related to the project file created in Visual Studio. Because I don't use Visual Studio, so I don't know how to do it. I'm more comfortable with command-line interface. I guess the purpose of inserting the .idl file into the project work space is to add a dependency relation, so if the .idl file is modified, the project in Visual Studio will do something accordingly, pretty much like a rule in Makefile. I don't know if this presumption is correct, and hope Visual Studio users can confirm it or correct it.

Secondly, after running `regsvr32` on the .dll file created when following the tutorial, how can I find the related entry in `oleview`? There is so much information, and no menu item Find for searching my COM interface. The GUI of `oleview` is quite confusing to me. Why are there different treeview branches, and what they mean? I can't find any useful information on Microsoft's website. Is there any technique to locate my COM interface? How can I make sure my COM interface is working?

`regsvr32` said the loading is successful, but I still cannot find my COM interface in `oleview`. Is it because I didn't insert the .idl file into the "project work space"? What is this "project work space" actually?

I don't even know what my COM interface shall look like in `oleview`, a UUID string or a human-readable name? So confusing this `oleview` is! Thanks.

Comment: 1) yes, just run midl.exe on the idl, 2) there are two COM worlds: the 32-bit and the 64-bit, related to what registry you used to register your component. There are also two versions of Oleview (x86 and x64), two versions of regsvr32, etc. So make sure you're using the corresponding one. In general, you want to look at "All Objects", and/or "Type Libraries" (aka .tlb files) and/or "Interfaces". There's no such thing as a "running instance'" unless you wrote a COM .exe server. A .dll can only be loaded by a client asking for it. https://flylib.com/books/en/3.294.1.109/1/

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for confirmation and the explanation. Really appreciate it. I've just done reading the article you recommend. Now I have a clue about oleview, but still don't know how to have my component listed in oleview? I ran regsvr32 on my .dll file, but nothing happened. Is it correct that running regsvr32 on the .dll file adds a registry entry for the COM interface provided by the .dll file? Is it correct that oleview populates its contents based on the registry? Thanks.

Comment: regsvr32 should at least display an "ok" messagebox. It "just" means DllRegisterServer  was called successfully. What it does exactly (in the registry or anywhere else) depends entirely on your DllRegisterServer impl. Again it can be a 32 vs 64 bit issue make sure which one you call exactly issue.https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/249873/how-to-use-the-regsvr32-tool-and-troubleshoot-regsvr32-error-messages OleView only list the registry yes, but ... again, oleview 32 sees 32bit registry, while oleview 64 sees 64bit registry

Comment: @SimonMourier Thank you. You help me a lot. Have a nice day. :)